# egrep match version number using grep

Tags: regex, unix, awk, sed, grep

If I have a string as follows: `DATABASE PATCH FOR EORQ (JAN2014 - 11.2.0.4.1)`

How would I go about matching the version number? I.e. I would like to extract `11.2.0.4.1`. I would like to avoid using sed and awk, as the line is arbitrary, and may change in the future, so I am looking for something which would match a version word containing digits as well as `.`'s.

I tried to use egrep as follows: `egrep -o "[0-9.]{1,}"` But it returns

```
2014

11.2.0.4.3
```

Thanks!

Comment: if you know that your line will contain one `-`, then you can use `cut` and extract the 2nd field, which is the version

Comment: @Bill I can't assume that

Comment: Why on earth would you want to rule out sed and awk for this? They are by far the most obvious candidate tools. Maybe you misunderstand how to use them? Post a few more sample input lines and expected output as with questions like this it's always easy to extract what you want, but much harder to exclude what you don't want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can probably use:

```
$ egrep -o "([0-9]{1,}\.)+[0-9]{1,}" file
11.2.0.4.1
```

- `([0-9]{1,}\.)+` matches at least one block of `[0-9]{1,}` and a dot `.`.
- `[0-9]{1,}` matches a block of `[0-9]`.

So this will match any block of `XX.YY`, being `XX` any amount of blocks of `ZZ.KK.TT.` and so on.

Answer (score 8):

You may try Perl regular expressions:

```
grep -Po "(\d+\.)+\d+"
```

Comment: It's not -P but -E flag :)

Comment: There is `-E`, and there is `-P`, and `-P` is more powerful. Unfortunately, not all operating systems support it (and `-o` too).